# I Need How to Create Issue on My New Repository on R Package I Just Created on GitHub

Tags: r, github, arima, r-package

I have a repository I created on GitHub [searchar](https://github.com/sta189332/searchar) which help to search for a given `seed` for a specific simulated univariate `ARIMA` data. How do I publicise it so as to get some review on its workability?

Comment: Make it public? Tweet it? Create an Issue yourself? Click [here](https://github.com/sta189332/searchar/issues) and create a new issue. Done! If you want it on CRAN, that's a different story. What do you mean by publicizing it? The best way to get reviews imo is to use twitter and/or just let it be on github. Eventually someone may find it and critique it.

Comment: Here's my review: Use meaningful file names, write tests, write a readme that tells us more about this package, automate the boring stuff (tests, ci, doc generation, issue closing, etc). There's a lot of code repetition in the main function, make repeated code a function (helper e.g.)

Comment: Usually a nice blast to a pertinent mailing list can find good target audience.